# Dynamically set version of PyQt app

Tags: python, json, pyqt4

I have a PyQt application and it has "About" window, where I show an author's name, contacts and version of application.

I want not to care much about changing this number every time the new version is released, so for now I use the following approach

1. I have a command line python script **compile.py**, which expects for version number and compiles with pyinstaller to exe

   `python compile.py 1.0.1`
2. This script then changes a version in json file - **data.json**

   `{version: 1.0.1;}`
3. Then, when executing "About" dialog, the version number gets retrieved from **data.json**

This is my temporary solution and I don't find it ideal. Are there any "best-practices" to deal with this situation?

Of course I can just store a variable for this purposes and change it every time, when new version is released, but It's even worse than my solution.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is, you've got to type out the new version string at least once *somewhere*, whether it's as a commandline argument or as a line in a file - so why not as a variable in your application?

Qt actually provides APIs for doing this, so you could have something like this at the beginning of your PyQt applications:

```
QApplication.setApplicationName('MyApp')
QApplication.setApplicationVersion('1.0.1')
```

Since these functions are static, the values can then be accessed from anywhere within the application (even before creating the `QApplication` object itself, which can be handy for commandline output, logging, etc).

Also, I see the version string as being part of the application, and so any changes to it should be included in the version control history (usually as part of a final commit before a new release is made).

Comment: Is there no (easier) way to get the version from setup.cfg? That's what I would expect as pip/Sphinx/... have options to look there for the version number...